# Whitespace characters as both a key and a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, whitespace, morse-code

I want to decode whole sentences from Morse code to normal alphabet - my script does just that, but it joins all words - it doesn't preserve spaces. In morseCode (the input) three spaces represent the separation between words, while one space represents the separation between letters.

I tried adding three spaces as a key to the dictionary with corresponding value of one space, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
def decodeMorse(morseCode):
    MORSE_CODE['   '] = ' '
    return ''.join(MORSE_CODE.get(i) for i in morseCode.split())
```

I also tried to separate input using regular expressions, but I failed. Is there a way to make it work using dictionaries? Is it even possible to use whitespaces as keys and inputs in dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split()` splits an input string on arbitrary-width whitespace. This means that you only get those sections of the string that are *not whitespace* (where whitespace includes spaces).

You'd normally split the input twice; once on the string `'    '` to get a list of words, then each word on whitespace to get just the letters:

```
def decodeMorse(morseCode):
    return ' '.join([
        ''.join([MORSE_CODE.get(i) for i in word.split()])
        for word in morseCode.split('   ')])
```

If you want to use your approach you'd have to use a regular expression to split *and include* 3-space separators:

```
re.split(r'([ ]{3}| )', morseCode)
```

but then you'd have to filter out the single-space letter separators, as `re.split()` can either include or not include the separator for the whole split operation, not for individual separator markers.

Comment: Thanks, I understand - it seems obvious now. Do you know if you can use whitespace as a key and/or value in a dictionary? I couldn't find any info.

Comment: Of course you can; it's just a string. The dictionary doesn't care what is *in* the string.

Answer (score 0):

The function `split` will consider the triple whitespace to be a single delimiter. So one option is to split first explicitly on triple space, as @Martijn Pieters suggests, or to first replace the triple space with something else that does not occur in Morse code (e.g. maybe `|`) and then translate that as a whitespace:

```
def decodeMorse(morseCode):
    MORSE_CODE['|'] = ' '
    return ''.join(MORSE_CODE.get(i) for i in morseCode.replace('   ', '|').split())
```